# Error in rendering xypic diagrams

Tags: xy-pic

I have a problem. The following code runs

```
\[\xymatrix{
 X \ar[d] \ar[r] & Y \ar[d]\\
 T                 & S\\} \]
```

Even the following runs

```
\[\xymatrix{
 X \ar[r] & Y \ar[d]\\
         & S\\} \]
```

But not this:

```
\[\xymatrix{
 X \ar[dr] \ar[r] & Y \ar[d]\\
                  & S\\} \]
```

My code is:

```
\documentclass[psamsfonts]{amsart}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage[all,arc]{xy}
\renewcommand{\char}{char}
\begin{document}

\[\xymatrix{
X   \ar[dr] \ar[r] & Y \ar[d]\\
             & S\\} \]
\end{document}
```

Comment: I have Windows 10. I use Overleaf.

Comment: It seems there is a problem with my macros. I am trying to narrow it down.

Comment: Oh my! I had redefined \char to say char. This seems similar to some other earlier post. Could you please tell me the reason for such mishap?

Comment: Could you please tell me why \renewcommand{\char}{char} causes the problem?

Comment: I have added my error-prone code above.

Answer (score 4):

`\char` is a TeX primitive. Redefining it is bound to break almost every LaTeX document.

This is like redefining `\box` or `\fi` or `\uppercase` (I remember of a class which did the latter).

Never do `\renewcommand` if you never heard about the command you'd like to redefine.